# saveHTML() in php adds unwanted tags

Tags: php, html, dom, tags

I've been in some trouble the past 2 weeks, I've spend much time researching this, no one else seems to have the same problem as I have. Now,  I have a file with `html` and `php` in it. I run that trough a simple code, that uses `DOM` then puts the result into a other file.

The html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php 
        if($_POST){
            $array = array(
                'username' => array(
                    'required' => true
                    ),    
                'password' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    )
                );
         }
    ?>
</head>
<body> 
     <p> Html works just fine </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I run this through a simple program, save it with the function `$dom->saveHTML()` and then put the result in another file with `file_put_contents()`.  It works fine, until I have an array like shown above, then it adds this into the php:

[image: Image op the <code>var_dump</code> result]

Yes, I have tried to add those things when loading the file into the DOM, but, it never removes the weird `<p>` tag, it just doesn't GO!

**More explanation:** Ok, so. I have a file, the first file you see. I load that in a string, I then `$dom->loadHTML($filestring)`. So, I loaded the file in `dom`. If I now save it with `$dom->saveHTML()` and put that result in a different file, I get this weird thing in my array, only with that kind of array ( You can see it on the 4th line of the picture, I `var_dumped` the string that I put into the file). Hopefully this makes more sense now.

I hope someone can help me out of my frustration, thanks for your time already.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are attempting to do and how you are trying to do it.

Comment: I doubt that PHP's DOMDocument is ment to parse files with mixed HTML and PHP. PHP != HTML/XML

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I understand it might have some problems here and there, why does it add tags though, I can not figure out how to let it just save what I change. And not change things itself, very annoying.

Comment: @etherealite hopefully my elaboration made it clearer.

Comment: Are you talking about the `<!DOCTYPE` tag? Or something else? It's not clear. Ah, I can click the image, now I see something has been added to the PHP code. Yes, you shouldn't use PHP in DOM.

Comment: Well, if it can't parse it correctly, you will most likely not get a correct output? What are you trying to accomplish by running a php-file through DOM Document in the first place?

Comment: Well, it's more about the HTML, otherwise it wouldn't make any sense, I know. I just wanted to parse through HTML and if there happend to be PHP in there, then I wanted to let it still work @MagnusEriksson Thank you for your help though! I'll have to do it in some other way then.....

Comment: The problem is that the DOM parser sees `=>` in the PHP, and thinks that's the end of the `<?php` tag. You can't put PHP in a DOM document.

Comment: If you would like to preserve the PHP then you need to pipe the text through a [parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser). Then you can pretty print the PHP back into its own file.